# Unable to developer unlock windows phone 8 device

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I want to test my app on windows phone 8 device. But to deploy any app on a device, we need to developer unlock it. I tried doing it using Visual Studio 2013. But when I try doing it-

I get 2 errors-
1.Check date and time .It does not match

2.Check your Microsoft credentials and try again.

Please help. Have tried alot.
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

To unlock your device with using developer account, be sure your device connect a available network,  and then retry it.